# chart.js how to add labels to plot

Tags: javascript, flask, chart.js

I'm using chart.js 4.2.1. I'm running a Flask server where I send scatter plot `data` together with `labels` to the webpage. The `labels` are sent as an string as follows: `['test1', 'test2', 'test3']`

```
const embedding_data = {
        datasets: [
            {
                type: 'line',
                data: [],
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(168, 38, 8)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(168, 38, 8)',
                pointRadius: 0,
                borderWidth: 3,
                order: 2
            },
            {
                type: 'scatter',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(168, 38, 8)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(168, 38, 8)',
                data: [],
                pointRadius: 3,
                order: 3
            },
            {
                type: 'scatter',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(46, 179, 84)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(46, 179, 84)',
                data: [],
                pointRadius: 3,
                order: 1
            },
            {
                type: 'scatter',
                labels: {{ labels }},
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(52, 110, 235)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(52, 110, 235)',
                data: {{ data }},
                pointRadius: 1,
                order: 4
            }
        ]
    };
    const config = {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: embedding_data,
        options: {  maintainAspectRatio: true,
                    events: [],
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    plugins:{
                        legend: {
                            display: false
                        },
                    },
                    scales:{
                        x: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        y: {
                            display: false
                        },
                    }
                 }
    };
    const myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config
    );
```

Using `data: {{ data }}` works without any problems but when I add `labels: {{ labels }}` I'm getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'` pointing to the line where I do `labels: {{ labels }}`. In the `labels` I don't have any `&`.

Is the syntax for labels that I'm using wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The quotation marks within the label declaration are escaped, hence the error message with the '&'.
To pass data to JavaScript within jinja I recommend the filter [`tojson`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson).

```
<script>
    const data = {
        labels: {{ labels | tojson }},
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My First Dataset',
            data: {{ data | tojson }},
        }],
    };
    const config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: {
            // ...
        }
    };
    const myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config
    );
</script>
```